# Debugging weirdness with BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, compact-framework

I have the following method:

```
protected void OnBarcodeScan(BarcodeScannerEventArgs e)
{
    if (BarcodeScan != null)
    {
        //BarcodeScan.BeginInvoke(e, null, null);
        BarcodeScan(e);
    }
}
```

When I try to step into the above method it works fine.  I am able to step in and over all the parts of the method.

However, if I switch the comment (so `BarcodeScan(e)` is commented out and remove the comment on `BarcodeScan.BeginInvoke(e, null, null)` then I cannot step into any part of the OnBarcodeScan method (ie a break point on `if (BarcodeScan != null)` does not get hit.

I tried putting some debug statements in there too.  But as long as that begin invoke call is in there it does not let me step into the method.

I checked the output and when I try to step in it says this:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in ScannerTest.exe
>   Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'Symbol.Marshaller.SymbolMessageWindow.WndProc'
>   Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.MessageWindow._WndProc'

Why would the whole method be un step able when there is a BeginInvoke in it?

Any help would be great!

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Have you tried inserting a `Debugger.Break()` statement? Sometimes that helps if breakpoints aren't being hit...

Comment: You definitely have it set on the Debug configuration and the DEBUG preproc is defined?

Comment: @JaredPar - Visual Studio 2008

Comment: @ctacke - I have it on debug config and the DEBUG preproc is checked in the project options.  I am able to do the debugging fine before I change the method.  Really all I do is swap the comment so that the BeginInvoke is called.  And it fails as I described.

Comment: This is a little voodoo, but the "without symbols" part makes me want to add a trivial declaration to `OnBarcodeScan` (say `int i = 17;`) just to see what'll happen...

Comment: How does this method get called?  By you directly, or is it a handler/delegate for something?

Comment: @ctacke - I have an event (barcode scanned) that calls a method.  In that method I call the method shown in my question.  I did try moving the BeginInvoke to the class that has the Scan Read event and when I did that break points in that method stopped working.  (This is really weird stuff!)

Comment: I don't really have an explanation.  The behavior suggests that the code is optimized and therefore there are no symbols for what you are trying to step into (hence Cameron's suggestion to try to make it so the method can't be optimized out).  This, though, should only happen if DEBUG is not defined.

Comment: @ctacke - I tried something similar to what Cameron suggested and it still did not work.  I looked Stephen Cleary's answer below and it links to the docs on BeginInvoke.  They clearly say that it is not supported on the compact framework.  :(  Because of that this question/problem becomes academic.  I will have to look for another solution to my problem.  (Thanks for looking into it though!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asynchronous delegate calls (i.e., `BeginInvoke`) are not supported by the Compact Framework.

As to the reason why the debugger will not even break into the method, I believe it is because of the following:

- `BeginInvoke`/`EndInvoke` methods are generated by the C# compiler (it is [required to do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)), marked as "native". This means the CLR will provide the implementation.
- The Compact Framework CLR [does not provide the implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).
- When the JIT compiler executes a method for the first time, it looks up all of the methods it may call (loading other assemblies, etc).
- Since the CLR doesn't support `Delegate.BeginInvoke`, any method that calls it cannot be JIT-compiled, and therefore cannot be executed.
- The `NotSupportedException` is thrown when `OnBarcodeScan` is first called (and the JIT-compiler attempts to compile it and fails). This is why it cannot be stepped into by the debugger.

Comment: This is a sweet answer!  Thanks a ton.  I ended up creating a thread and calling Invoke from in the thread.  That works fine.